# How to preserve tab indents in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am attempting to have Word (2011 Mac) start the next line at the exact same indent as the line above it. This is in order for me to more easily type formatted code into my notes, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMamz.jpg).

It would speed up writing my embedded code in my notes if I didn't have to constantly tab back to the current place. I'm not sure what the solution is. In some text editors I know you can hold shift+enter to keep the tab indent the same, but it isn't working in Word.

If there is no way to fix this, would someone please recommend me a native mac application that has basic RTF and the ability to preserve tab indents.

Comment: have a look here: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T007352_Controlling_Automatic_Indenting.html